# Recover data from corrupted Windows partition

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, data-recovery

I know that Windows file system is corrupted or missing...in fact I can't boot it and when trying to mount it with:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda3 /temp/ -t ntfs
```

i got

```
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda1': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sda1' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

I need to recover some pictures and some documents from there...is there anything I can try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though you can't mount it, you can read the filesystem with [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) and recover files from it.

[TestDisk Step-by-Step](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step) will help you through the process.

Comment: thanks!! i made it!! now...next step...as this is a vaio laptop and it won't let me boot factory's recovery partition...any clue about how i might fix it? i will otherwise have to install a blank copy of seven hoping it will automatically find all drivers...

Comment: Yeah, you will probably have to do a fresh install. Or just do away with Windows.

Comment: that's not so simple...some programs that i need runs only (or better) under windows...thanks anyway